# How to use logic to determine redirect path using Symfony's .yml?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

First off, I'm comfortable with PHP, but don't know much about Symfony. That being said, I'm looking to help an open source project close out some bugs and one of the things in question is redirecting the user to their profile, unless the page they were on before logging in was a specific post, in which case, redirect back to that post after logging in.

Any idea how to do this? Having a hard time finding anything in the Symfony docs.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing about it in the documentation, but there's a good blog post about it.

[Set up an AuthenticationSuccessHandler in Symfony2](http://blog.alterphp.com/2011/10/set-up-authenticationsuccesshandler.html)